# ActiveRecord singleton dangerous?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, singleton

I write the following code. The purpose is to avoid query to my database with active record.

The only reason to made a request to the databse is an update (after_save).

```
class Configuration < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.instance
    ConfigurationSingleton.instance.active_record_instance
  end

  class ConfigurationSingleton
    include Singleton

    def initialize
      @active_record_instance = Configuration.first || Configuration.new
    end

    def active_record_instance
      @active_record_instance
    end
  end

  after_save Proc.new { ConfigurationSingleton.instance.active_record_instance.reload }
end
```

It seem to work well in developement mode but i feel insecure. 
Does this code safe running with apache passenger on production with several separate process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have several different processes running this code then you could end up with a "singleton" per process. You'd definitely have the issue if you have multiple application servers.

The problem will be that the only process that will reload the instance will be the one that the save happens on. None of the other processes will know that it has changed unless the instance is saved on those processes too.

So:

1. App server 1 loads instance
2. App server 2 loads instance
3. Instance changes on app server 1
4. App server 1 reloads instance
5. **App server 2 continues with old instance**

Answer (score 1):

You can easily eliminate the risk of a race condition by putting a unique index on a column and setting that column to a fixed value when you create the singleton. Just be sure to handle the SQL exception when there is a duplicate.

```
create_table :app_settings do |t|
  t.integer :unique, null: false, default: 1
  t.boolean :haz_mojo
end
add_index :app_settings, :unique, unique: true
```

Another option would be to, after creating the singleton, select the row with the lowest id instead of continuing with the created reference.